# Poor Peformance with BIG IP F5 WCF NetTCpBinding

Tags: performance, wcf, nettcpbinding, f5

I am facing issue of poor performance when used WCF having NetTcpbinding with Load Balancer

We have win form application which consumes WCF (net.tcp protocol). In production we have web Farm having 3 servers with load balancer (F5). WCF hosted in IIS. We are testing with only 1 user

Now when we point WCF to specific server (using either server name or IP); application really perform well. However when we give the DNS name (so that request is pass through load balancer) there is a significant drop in performance. Network team is saying from there side everything is properly working. Please help

Following is the configuration that i have tin WCF web.config file.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
 <diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="GetProxyEnabled" name="companyname.InvOps.ServiceLayer.PAServiceServer">
    <host>
          <baseAddresses>
<add baseAddress="net.tcp://USHOUIOWEB012VT/PAService"/>
            <!--<add baseAddress="net.tcp://xxx.uat.companyname.net/PAService/"/>-->
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="netTcpAddress" behaviorConfiguration="NetTcpEndPointBehaviour" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding" contract="companyname.InvOps.ServiceLayer.IPAService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GetProxyEnabled">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentInstances="400" maxConcurrentSessions="200"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NetTcpEndPointBehaviour">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding" 
                 closeTimeout="05:45:00"
                 openTimeout="05:45:00"
                 receiveTimeout="05:45:00"
                 sendTimeout="05:45:00"
     transactionFlow="false" 
     transferMode="Buffered" 
     transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" 
     hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
     listenBacklog="10" 
     maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
     maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
     maxConnections="10" 
     maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" 
      maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
      maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" 
                           inactivityTimeout="05:45:00"
                           enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Really appretiate any feedback or suggesttion. Also what is the recommended settings on F5 when used WCF with NetTcpBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working now. It was Load Balance configuration issue. We have changed the Virtual Server type from Standard to Performance (Layer 7). The performance is not improved to acceptable range.